# Here API: is there an output format for GIS desktop

Tags: here-api

I have used ["Calculate Isoline" here API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resources.html) and I have a JSON output with the coordinates of the isochrone lines. This is an output example: https://gist.github.com/aborruso/68ccd0488f0f92d9518abf78d9393636

Is there a way to produce natively an output format file that I can open in desktop GIS? Is there a geojson output?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't way to produce natively an output format for Desktop GIS.
But we have a sample to extract JSON output from the API to GeoJson format.
Please have a look at below sample url.
https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/geojson_route_extraction

I hope this help!

Comment: It would help me, if it was possible to view the code that do the conversion. Could you share it here? What about to add geojson output as feature/option?